# IIS reverse proxy with windows authentication on same server getting access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, kerberos-delegation

I've viewed a few of the other IIS reverse proxy with windows authentication posts on here and they don't seem to be what I'm trying to do. Hopefully someone will be able to help or spot what I'm not doing or doing wrong.

I've got a server which has a website running on port 80 which I need to present a number of other web applications on. I cannot create new hostnames so I created a virtual directory in the site which pointed to my web apps, however the root site is using .net2.0 app pool which must stay as .net2.0 whereas my ASP.NET MVC apps all need 4.0 app pools. As per the web.config inheritance problem this is not working and I cannot change the web.config in the root to ignore propagation to child web.configs - with me so far? ;-)

To cut a long story short I've now got a virtual directory in my port 80 site which is acting as a reverse proxy to another site on port 81 and this is working fine for anonymous connections. I've tested it with a simple HTML page and I can access it and the url re-writing is working on links in the HTML page, all good so far.

Now I need to enable windows authentication on the port 81 site, so I followed the instructions similar to what is in these links on MSDN site to configure SPN's for the domain account I'm using (DOMAIN\testaccount) and other IIS config's:-

[link 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2015/08/03/configure-application-request-routing-with-windows-authentication-kerberos/)
[link 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/06/04/a-quick-solution-when-windows-authentication-is-required-on-backend-web-server-for-arr-scenario/)

The problem is that all I get now is the good old error message:-

> Access is denied.  Description: An error occurred while accessing the
>   resources required to serve this request. The server may not be
>   configured for access to the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280

I've tried creating a test aspx page which just outputs the server variables to the response but even this is not working.

I can't find anything else to try, initially I thought I'd have to get Kerberos sorted to pass the details from virtual directory to site on port 81 but the MSDN posts say this is not needed, just the SPN's.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be something very simple and me being dumb for not checking! :-)

I spent days trying to figure out why this wasn't working, not sure why I didn't try earlier but I changed the application pool it was running under to use .net2.0 and then my test aspx page worked!?!

Turns out in IIS manager if you click on the root server node itself that under 'ISAPI and CGI restrictions' feature settings that the .net4.0 DLL's were set to 'Not Allowed' but the .net2.0 DLL's were 'Allowed'! I just enabled the .net4.0 changed the application pool back and then voila it works.